# maven multi-module pom and jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

I have a hierarchy of poms, with a parent pom that all other poms inherit from (possibly transitively). How should jobs be set up in jenkins for  this ? Should there be one job pr project/pom, or just a single job pointing to the top level pom ? 
My goal is obviously to have jenkins build only  what is required after a change. A single job pointing to the top level pom seems to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the master pom. It will do the rest. Just make sure you checkout everything you need from svn or git or  whatever scm you use.

Edit: there is an option in Jenkins to build incremental. This is what you need.

Comment: You mean "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" ?

Comment: No, i cannot access my jenkins now, but it should be under advanced build settings

Comment: Great, found it. The only thing that puzzles me now is that when I click modules, only the modules that were built during the last build are blue, the other that did not have to be compiled are grey. I would have expected them to be blue since thy were successfully built n builds ago (n > 1).

Comment: This is because it is using a maven setting which makes it possible to build only some modules instead of all. See http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/

Comment: You have to know there can be an unwanted side effect. If an incremental build fails (e.g. on module B), this module will not be rebuild on the next build (if there were no commits in that module). The only solution I found is trigger a manual build from Jenkins itself, which will build all modules.

Comment: FYI, this will also not work if you branch your submodules. i.e. if each submodule has its own life cycle